# What is wrong with my GUI program

Tags: java, user-interface

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;

public class Car {

private int xLeft;
private int yTop;

public Car(int x, int y){
    xLeft =x;
    yTop=y;
}

public void draw(Graphics2D g2){
    Rectangle body = new Rectangle(xLeft, yTop+10, 60, 10);
    Ellipse2D.Double frontTire= new Ellipse2D.Double(xLeft+10, yTop+20, 10,     10);
     Ellipse2D.Double rearTire= new     Ellipse2D.Double(xLeft+40,yTop+20,10,10);
    Point2D.Double r1 = new Point2D.Double(xLeft+10,yTop+10);
    Point2D.Double r2 = new Point2D.Double(xLeft+20,yTop);
    Point2D.Double r3 = new Point2D.Double(xLeft+40,yTop);
    Point2D.Double r4 = new Point2D.Double(xLeft+50,yTop+10);
    Line2D.Double frontWindshield = new  Line2D.Double(r1,r2);
    Line2D.Double roofTop = new  Line2D.Double(r2,r3);
    Line2D.Double rearWindshield = new  Line2D.Double(r3,r4);

    g2.draw(body);
    g2.draw(frontTire);
    g2.draw(rearTire);
    g2.draw(frontWindshield);
    g2.draw(roofTop);
    g2.draw(rearWindshield);
 }
}

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class CarComponent extends  JComponent {
public void paintCompnent(Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    Car car1 = new Car(0,0);
     int x = getWidth()-60;
     int y = getHeight()-30;

     Car car2 = new Car(x,y);
     car1.draw(g2);
     car2.draw(g2);
 }
}

import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class CarViewer {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(400,500);
    frame.setTitle("Two Cars");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    CarComponent component = new CarComponent();
    frame.add(component);

    frame.setVisible(true);
    }

 }
```

I have looked at this code for hours, but can't figure out what is wrong. Its copied right out of the textbook. When I hit run, only an empty box shows up. Its supposed to show cars, one on top left, one on bottom right.

Comment: Rename `paintCompnent` to `paintComponent`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `paintComponent` is misspelled and so it does not override the superclass method. Hence, only the default method that draws a blank box is called.

There is a way to avoid this common bug down the road, with the `@Override` annotation. By adding this annotation to all methods that either override a superclass method or implement an interface method, your compiler will stop with an error if you mistype the method name, rather than creating a difficult-to-debug error:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    // code here
}
```